# How to customize WebApi OAuth token validation?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

**Context**

I have a working WebApi2 application, which uses the out of the box bearer token validation, just as was in the original Visual Studio project template.

I would like to add a custom data to the generated token, then check against that custom data when the subsequent api calls happen what are presenting this token.

For the sake of example say I would like to store the IP address of the caller when the token was created, then when validating the token check if the call which is uses the token have the very same IP.

I found the custom class

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
```

in my project and I also see that `OAuthOptions` is configured to use that custom class in start up.

I suppose where to add my custom token data (the ip):

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
```

here I can add it to the ticket properties as custom data.

**Question**

However I can not find out in what method to check against the token has this data, and it matches to the actual call's ip, and if not, then regard the token invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right when you decided to implement `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` . Now you need to add something like this:

```
        private ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(User user, string authenticationType)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Login));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserID.ToString())); // or ip instead of user.UserID if you need
        return identity;
    }
```

And then use it in your `Grant...` method (for instance `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`) like this:

```
        ClaimsIdentity identity = CreateIdentity(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        context.Validated(identity);
```

Then when request come to your webapi controller you can check your data in your custom Attribute:

```
            Claim userIdClaim = ((ClaimsIdentity)actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity)
            .Claims
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Remaining in the IP sample, it is not clear for me where and when and how to check _against_ the stored IP, and _reject_ the request as invalid?

Comment: @g.pickardou After the user has passed the authorization and you save his ip in the claim you can create your own attribute (inherit ActionFilterAttribute) to validate incoming requests. Then in OnActionExecuting you can write:

Comment: `var owinContext = (OwinContext)actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"];
string ip = owinContext.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
Claim userIpClaim = ((ClaimsIdentity)actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity)
    .Claims
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
if (userIpClaim == null
  && string.CompareOrdinal(userIpClaim.Value, ip) != 0)
{
    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    return;
}`

Comment: Now append your newly created attribute to any action of apicontroller and if the user doesn't have appropriate claim or has a different ip address then he will get '401 Unauthorized'.